# how to get clipbpard share on a non-X CentOS VirtualBox guest

Tags: centos, virtualbox, clipboard

I have a CentOS guest on my archlinux system.

In the VM I have installed:

- VirtualBox guest additions
- GPM

cut and paste *does* work with VMs that have X and with Windows VMs.

Is it just not possible to do clipboard sharing with a non-X linux with VirtualBox?